# Conditionally display an image in webgrid - mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, grid, webgrid

In my webgrid I need to display images based on the value .. Code is given below

```
@model TraktorumMVC.Models.ManagePhotos
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManagePhotos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.AdPhotos);
}


    @grid.GetHtml(
       displayHeader: false,
       columns: grid.Columns(
             grid.Column(format: (item) =>
                 {
                     if (item.IsMainPreview == true)
                     {
                         return @<text><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif")" alt="Image "/></text>;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         return @<text><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/non-preview-photo.gif")" alt="Image "/></text>;
                     }
                 }
                ),               
             grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Remove Photo", "RemovePhoto", "Images", new { photoID = @item.Id }, new { @class = "RemovePhoto" }))
         ));
```

I am not sure how can i use `if` in webgrid . I just tried that .Its not working .getting following  error

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the`grid.Column` method's `format` parameter you are putting together a lambda expression so that you can of course use `if`. But the problem is you cannot use `@` when you are in "code mode" in Razor to output HTML. So you need to wrap the image tag creation into an HtmlHelper (like the built in `Html.ActionLink` there are lots of [examples](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)) or use the HTML.Raw method to return HTML:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    displayHeader: false,
    columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(format: (item) =>
                {
                    if (item.IsMainPreview == true)
                    {
                        return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif")));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/Content/images/non-preview-photo.gif")));                         
                    }
                }
            ),               
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Remove Photo", "RemovePhoto", "Images", new { photoID = item.Id }, new { @class = "RemovePhoto" }))
        ));
```

Also in the last line instead of `new { photoID = @item.Id }` you should write `new { photoID = item.Id }`
To learn more about razor here is a detailed [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax).

Comment: This works great in MVC3. Would you know how to get it to work in MVC4 without the URL.Content.  I've posted a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711753/conditionally-display-an-image-in-webgrid-mvc-4

Comment: I voted this one in the past and it just helped me again. If I could I'd give you 100 votes! :D

Comment: @LenielMacaferi I'm glad that my answer helped you :) you know that there is a [bounty system on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) ;)

Comment: Yes, I know. The bounty system is for the case when there's no accepted answer and one wants someone else to give a better answer to that unanswered question. :)

Comment: Great, I struggled for more than one hour to get this.. thanks