# Conditionally display an image in webgrid

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

nemesv's code [Conditionally display an image in webgrid - mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866051/conditionally-display-an-image-in-webgrid-mvc-3) works great in MVC3.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
  displayHeader: false,
  columns: grid.Columns(
           grid.Column(format: (item) =>
             {
               if (item.IsMainPreview == true)
             {
                return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif")));
             }
```

In MVC4 you don't need Url.Content to use the "~". I haven't been succesful in getting the code to work without the Url.Content (it can't find the image).  I have tried

```
return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", "~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif"));
```

and

```
return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src={0} alt=\"Image\"/></text>", "~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif"));
```

among others.  Does anyone know how to get this to work in MVC4 without the URL.Content?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It this case it doesn't work without the `Url.Content`

Because the `~` replacement only works if you have it directly in your Razor template (Razor does this replacement when it parses your `.cshtml` and generates the response).

But the `grid.GetHtml` will return the rendered html which gets written into the response without any Razor parsing.

You can test it with the following code snippet (just copy into any `.cshtml`):

```cs
<img src="~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif" />

@{
    var img =  "<img src=\"~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif\" />";
}

@Html.Raw(img)
```

The first image will be displayed correctly because Razor parses it and does the `~` replacement but the second won't because the html just written as a string into the response and no parsing is involved.