# If else in Web Grid Column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

How to put a condition (if else) in webgrid column?

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("RealName", "Name"),
                grid.Column("UserName", "Email")
                ))
```

I have to show the Email Column based on a condition, How to do this?

Comment: Try this
may be Duplicate of  [this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866051/conditionally-display-an-image-in-webgrid-mvc-3

Comment: I have to show / hide column based on a condition, The above thread shows or hides the column value, so its not duplicate.

Comment: then modify your question to `if else for WebGrid column`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this

```
@{
    var gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    gridColumns.Add(grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Select", "Details")));
    if (true)
    {
        gridColumns.Add(grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")));
    }

    gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("UserName", "name"));
    gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("RealName", "RealName"));
}

@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(gridColumns.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Thank you @Nilesh, looks like the cleanest way of doing this

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me.

```
 @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        selectedRowStyle: "select",
        columns: grid.Columns(




        grid.Column("Is Active",format: (item) =>
            {
                if (item.IsActive == true)
                {
                    return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img height='20' width='20' src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/images/rightmark.png")));
                }
                else
                {
                    return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img height='20' width='20' src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/Content/images/non-preview-photo.gif")));                         
                }
            }, style: "firstColumn",canSort:true),       
        grid.Column("Name", " Name", style: "SecondColumn",canSort:true),       
        grid.Column("Role", "Role", style: "ThirdColumn",canSort:true)
))
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way is

```
if(myConditionCanGoInHere) {

   @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("RealName", "Name"),
            grid.Column("UserName", "Email")
            ))

}
else{

 @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("RealName", "Name"),
            //grid.Column("UserName", "Email")
            ))
// Here remove your email column

))
```

[Reference](http://forums.asp.net/p/1669919/4371225.aspx?WebGrid%20conditional%20content) and [Here](http://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/if-condition-or-for-loop-in-a-mvc-webgrid/)

Comment: thankx for answer, but how do i put entire column in condition. So if condition is true then the column displays & vice versa.

Comment: @Anup Check the updated answer it's a very basic answer check if it works for you .

Answer (score 2):

I update the code to accept parameter: (Razor View - Webmatrix)

```
      grid.Column("Unread",format: (item) =>
        {
            if (item.Unread == true)
            {
                return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><a \"target=\"_blank\" href=\"ViewComments?bvnum={0}\"><img height='20' width='20' border='0' src=\"/images/new_comments.png\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", @item.id));
            }
            else
            {
                return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><a \"target=\"_blank\" href=\"ViewComments?bvnum={0}\"><img height='20' width='20' border='0' src=\"/images/comments.png\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", @item.id));
            }
        }, canSort:true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be good, if you validate this before you put the data in the GUI layer.
You have to get the right data for the grid in your Controller. So you can only show the data in the grid and you don't have to mind if it is the right data because you have already validate it.

That mean you have to put the if/else in your controller not in your view.

```
        public JsonResult GetServiceGridData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var services = ModelTransformer.Transform(Repository.Instance.GetServices());
            foreach (var service in services)
            {
                var filterType = _filterTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == service.FilterTypeId);
                service.FilterTypeName = filterType == null ? _filterTypeNoneName : filterType.Name;
            }
            return Json(services.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Something like this for example

Comment: I am looking for quick fix buddy.

Comment: Then look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866051/conditionally-display-an-image-in-webgrid-mvc-3) one :) @Anup

Comment: Well i cannot change in controller, since it is being used by multiple users.

Comment: Klick on "This" in my last answer...
There you don't have to change the Controller...